# Does this sentence make sense in German? (Was kaufen Sie Herrn Braun?)

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

Does this sentence make sense in German?

> Was kaufen Sie Herrn Braun?

Does it mean the following?

> What are you buying for Mr. Braun?

I think the *n* in Herr*n* is a sign of dative.

Comment: Did you look up *kaufen* in a dictionary which lists the tenses that go which each verb? Is dative listed there?

Comment: @RHa
Ich kaufe dir (dative) ein Buch (accusative).

Comment: @RHa I think you mean cases, not tenses

Comment: @Nariman Asgharian that's right, I meant cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your analysis is right.

> Was [accusative] kaufen Sie [nominative] Herrn Braun [dative]?
>
> <sub>(What are you buying for Mr. Braun?)</sub>

Comment: Note the comma in the following example: `Was kaufen Sie Frau Braun?` vs `Was kaufen Sie, Frau Braun?` The first sentence is dative, the second one is nominative (What are you buying, Mrs Braun?)